# VBA to paste data to specific cell based on column and row criteria

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am trying to have a button that will snapshot a number to another sheet. The copy/paste code works as it should however I need it to paste accordingly to the proper user and week.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub CopyScore()

Worksheets("Scorecard").Range("AD13").Copy
Worksheets("Yearly").Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Obviously, this just paste to B2

How can I make this where in the Yearly sheet it needs to look for a specific name in column A and also a specific number in Row A?

Just to make more sense... It will be looking at a name on the Scorecard (D2) sheet then matching that to a name in column A. It will also be looking at the week #(V2) on the Scorecard sheet and matching that to the column in Yearly.

If this was able to be written for another sheet on the same workbook and another code for a workbook that is not open that would be amazing...

So this works great!

```
Sub demo()
Dim ySht As Worksheet, ce As Range
Dim c As Range, oWBook As Workbook
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scorecard")
    If .Range("AD13") <> "" Then
        Set oWBook = Workbooks.Open("d:\temp\my.xlsx") ' updated as needed
        Set ySht = oWBook.Worksheets("Yearly")
        ' Search name
        Set c = ySht.Columns(1).Find(.Cells(2, "D"))
        If Not c Is Nothing And .Range("V2") > 0 Then
            Set ce = ySht.Cells(c.Row, 1).Offset(0, .Range("V2"))
            ce.Value = .Range("AD13")
            ce.AddComment
            ce.Comment.Text .Range("B29").Value
        End If
        oWBook.Save
        oWBook.Close
    End If
End With
```

End Sub

However, if B29 is blank I get an error since there is no text for the comment.

Also is there a way to make it so that if the "Yearly" worksheet cell is not blank it will not send the score? This would eliminate changing the score after it has been submitted.

Comment: What's the location of ` the column in Yearly.'?

Comment: Column "A" is the location.

Comment: Please share the screenshots of your worksheets. Also, share some examples of what needs to be copied where and the logic behind it. It looks like a simple lookup that could be handled using a formula using `INDEX/MATCH` (in older versions) or `XLOOKUP` (in Microsoft 365). If you already have a formula you have tried, please share it.

Comment: Here is the file. https://file.io/8SMYNkzqozdh The issue is that once you select a different associate all information changes based on their name. I would like this to be a button so I can snap shot their score to the yearly sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```vb
Sub demo()  ' [Stop updating]
    Dim ySht As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, ce As Range
    Set ySht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Yearly")
    With Worksheets("Scorecard")
        If .Range("AD13") <> "" Then
            ' Search name
            Set c = ySht.Columns(1).Find(.Cells(2, "D"))
            If Not c Is Nothing And .Range("V2") > 0 Then
                Set ce = ySht.Cells(c.Row, 1).Offset(0, .Range("V2"))
                ce.Value = .Range("AD13")
                ce.AddComment
                ce.Comment.Text .Range("B29").Value
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

> Question: If I wanted to do this to a workbook that is closed. e.g. The "scorecard" workbook would be open and then it would send the number to a workbook that is closed.

> Answer: The main code logic is same. The only different is the code to open/close the target workbook.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim ySht As Worksheet, ce As Range
    Dim c As Range, oWBook As Workbook
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scorecard")
        If .Range("AD13") <> "" Then
            Set oWBook = Workbooks.Open("d:\temp\my.xlsx") ' updated as needed
            Set ySht = oWBook.Worksheets("Yearly")
            ' Search name
            Set c = ySht.Columns(1).Find(.Cells(2, "D"))
            If Not c Is Nothing And .Range("V2") > 0 Then
                Set ce = ySht.Cells(c.Row, 1).Offset(0, .Range("V2"))
                ' "Yearly" worksheet cell is blank
                If Len(ce.Value) = 0 Then
                    ce.Value = .Range("AD13")
                    ' Comment cell is not blank
                    If Len(.Range("B29").Value) > 0 Then
                        ce.AddComment
                        ce.Comment.Text .Range("B29").Value
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            oWBook.Save
            oWBook.Close
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If I wanted to do this to a workbook that is closed.. how different would the code have to be?

Comment: Are both sheets in a closed workbook?

Comment: The "scorecard" workbook would be open and then it would send the number to a workbook that is closed.

Comment: Several lines are needed to get it done. I have updated the code.

Comment: Amazing... You are great. I cannot thank you enough.

Comment: Taller_ExcelHome, If i wanted to also add the the notes section as a comment to the cell how can i do this? I have it where it is creating the comment but it will not copy the contents of the cell...

            Set c = ySht.Columns(1).Find(.Cells(2, "D"))
            If Not c Is Nothing And .Range("V2") > 0 Then
                ySht.Cells(c.Row, 1).Offset(0, .Range("V2")).AddComment ("B29")

Comment: Hmmm this gives me a runtime error of 1004.

ySht.Cells(c.Row, 1).Offset(0, .Range("V2")).AddComment ySht.Range("B29")

Comment: Error 1004 for the line with .Comment.Text .Range("B29").Value

Comment: Works! Amazing... I need your brain... Thank you again... If i need anymore help would you be ok with me commenting here again?

Comment: Yes, it is a minor change on it. Otherwise a new post would be helpful for SO users.

Comment: Ok... found an issue. If the "Notes" section is blank i get an error. anyway to fix this? Also is there a way to "Block" a score being overwritten if it has already been submitted? Sorry...

Comment: What does ` "Notes" section is blank` mean? Please give the detail about overwritten issue on OP.

Comment: Added to the OP.

Comment: If B29 is blank, do you want to add a blank comment or skip adding comment?

Comment: Skip adding a comment.